# How to copy a gzipped data stream to a file in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, .net-core

I'm trying to stream a large file from a remote system to a local file using F#.  The stream contains gzipped data.  Here's the code I've been trying to get working:

```
            let client = new HttpClient()
            let! gzippedDataStream = client.GetStreamAsync(uri) |> Async.AwaitTask
            using (new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) (fun fs ->
                using (new MemoryStream()) (fun outputMemStream ->
                    using (new GZipStream(gzippedDataStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)) (fun gzipStream ->
                        gzipStream.CopyTo outputMemStream
                    )
                    outputMemStream.CopyTo fs
                )
            )
```

When this runs, a file is created but no content is written.  I think this is probably because some stream isn't being flushed at the right time, but I've tried a few different orderings and still can't get it working.  Does anybody see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: I don't know F#. But you can directly copy to the `FileStream` without using the `MemoryStream`, from the [code example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Or maybe this is the cause, after the call `CopyTo` is completed, the position of the `outputMemStream` does not be reset to the beginning, so when copying from `outputMemStream` to `fs`, you are starting from the end of the `outputMemStream` so not a single byte is copied at all.

Comment: [Copying begins at the current position in the current stream, and does not reset the position of the destination stream after the copy operation is complete.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Good call about CopyTo.  Using `outputMemStream.Seek(int64 0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` to reset the cursor also solved the issue.  I ended up just copying directly to the file stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can either write directly to the FileStream, or you can call the `WriteTo` method on MemoryStream instead of `CopyTo`.